# why some configuration in AndroidManifest goes inside "application" section and some not?

Tags: android, android-manifest

While writing Android manifest some configuration I must put inside "application" section (eg. list of activities) and some outside it (eg. uses-sdk). Why? Is there any general rule what goes inside "application" section and what outside? Or was it pure random arbitrary decision by Android creators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a programming question. If you follow commit history of AOSP you might get an answer. Or track down Andy Rubin and ask him :)

With the current layout, you could theoretically have multiple applications inside the same APK. Stuff that is common to all applications will got at the highest level (`uses-sdk`, etc.), everything else inside the corresponding `<application>`.

Comment: Great. But then, what configuration is common to all applications and what is application specific was decided arbitrary? For instance: I don't see any reason why minimal SDK version should be common to all applications. And it is purely theoretical, because anyway I can't have multiple Application tags in manifest? (docs say so)

Comment: Well, if the on the same device, they should have the same minimal SDK requirements. And in our theoretical setup, '<application>' does not equal an APK. Think of it as another component of the app, just like services and activities. You can be pretty sure that whoever designed the format didn't just throw in stuff at random :)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely it is not a random decision. 
The Format is something like you have define the configurations pertaining to any application such as its activities and services inside  tag because ofcourse they are related to your application.
And General libraries you use and Permissions outside of the  tag which complement your application.

Take a note of the structure of the manifest file [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

To get concept in detail try [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)